# FileSystemWatcher stops raising events after some time

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am using `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor newly added files in several folders. `FileSystemWatcher` is created for N number of folders/directories to watch separately. It works fine at the start but after some time it doesn't raise any events. Am I missing something here? Any inputs/help is much appreciated.

```
// Set up FileSystemWatchers for the specific subdirectories.
foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoriesToWatch)
{
    string subdirectoryPath = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, subdirectory);
    FileSystemWatcher subdirectoryWatcher = CreateWatcher(subdirectoryPath, true);
    subdirectoryWatcher.Created += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"File created in {subdirectory}: {e.Name}");
    };
}
```

I have increased the `InternalBufferSize` as well and it's going to filter the properties as well by based on file mask provided.

Comment: are your  FileSystemWatcher  instances getting collected?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.keepalive?view=net-7.0

Comment: Outside the actual problem: increasing the buffer size only makes sense if you know what you are doing. If you do it "just in case" it will likely only postpone the error, at best.

Comment: Also: in your oncoming development, make sure to spend as little time in that event handler as possible. If events arrive faster than are processed, they will pile up and finally you will miss some.

Comment: I am disposing it properly also, not sure why it fires the events for first few files and when file arrives after let's say 10-15 minutes later, it doesn't fire it